# How to export simplex tabular using PULP

Tags: python, linear-programming

I want to solve a linear programming problem with python. Currently, I am using PULP. If I choose 'primalsimplex' method, is there any way for me to print the final simplex tabular?

Answer (score 0):

No. First of all, PuLP is not a solver. It is a modeling tool, that is a front-end for a solver. Having said that, all practical LP solvers don't work with tableaux. They all use versions of the revised Simplex method.  They have no tableaux and thus will never export them. Actually, they don't even allow exporting the basis inverse, because practical SImplex methods don't work directly with a basis inverse.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have a follow-up question, then it is possible for me to check whether my problem has multiple optimal solutions with PULP? Because you  know that with the simplex tableaux, we can check the properties of the optimal solutions

Comment: And could please explain what the 'revise simplex' here refers to. Because I tried to search it on google and it seems that the revised simplex method still needs simplex table. Thank you again :)

Comment: No, it works with a (sparse) factorization of the basis matrix. Not with a tableau.

Comment: You need to check for degeneracy to see if there are multiple solutions.

Comment: Thank you so much and sorry for the disturbance again. How can I check the degeneracy vis PULP? It seems that I cannot print out the values of basis variables vis PULP.